# Issues with XML Serializer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xmlserializer

Here is my code

```
private void parseCurrentPersonData(string aRespString)
{
    // converting string to stream
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(aRespString);
    MemoryStream personXml = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    if (personXml != null)
    {
        personXerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(person));
        currentPerson = (person)personXerializer.Deserialize(personXml);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

and a class

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class person
{
        [XmlElement("first-name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("last-name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("headline")]
        public string Headline { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("headline")]
        public string Interests { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

on this line

```
personXerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(person));
```

Please help

Comment: share your xml structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be because you have two XmlElements that have the same name?

Comment: Yes!! That solved my issue!! I am hitting myself for not being able to see that!!